# should I not accept cookies for the sake of anonymity?

Tags: vpn, cookies, google, gmail

Let's say I had a Gmail account. Should I just not have a Gmail account, or should I not use their cookies? How bad are the cookies, in of themselves? I obviously wouldn't log into it, with my VPN or Tor. But what do you think of Google's log in cookies?

Comment: You need to do more than disable cookies to stay anonymous, many browsers leak a lot of uniquely  identifying data. According to [this site](https://panopticlick.eff.org), my browser leaks around 22 bits of a identifying information and my browser is unique among the 4 million visitors to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are used to retain information between visits to a website. This gives website the ability to remember you between visits. This allows them to provide better service, but also gives them the opportunity to analyze your long-term behavior.

Disabling cookies is a tradeoff between privacy and convenience. You have to decide for yourself if you want to allow website to recognize you immediately when you visit them or if you want to tell them yourself who you are by logging in with username and password.

Keep in mind that there are also ways to handle cookies between the two extremes "allow everywhere" and "reject completely".

1. Many browsers can be configured to only keep cookies until the browser is closed. This allows web applications which rely on cookies to work properly, but doesn't allow them to track you over longer timespans.
2. There are browser plugins which give you finer control over which websites are allowed to store cookies and which aren't. That way you can prevent advertisement networks from tracking you, but still allow your favorite discussion forum to set your login cookie.

There is little reason to visit an email service like GMail without logging in, so allowing them to set cookies is merely for your convenience because it means you don't have to enter your username and password everytime you visit them. However, keep in mind that when you share your computer with other people, you might prefer to not use cookies, because when you forget to "log out" manually, other users of the same computer will gain access to your email account just by visiting GMail. When they also use GMail they might not even notice that they are in your account.

Comment: So Gmail doesn't do anything bad with my cookies? Because I thought google tracked people.

Comment: @user3695903 Sure they track you. But most of the information about your websurfing behavior on non-google services is obtained through the cookies set and read by AdSense advertising and the Google Analytics service which are embedded on lots and lots of websites and from your behavior on the Google search engine.